# ERROR: Cannot find "/config/config.json". Have you run "sequelize init"?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile for my API project using Node.js - Express.js

**api.dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9.3.0

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && npm install nodemon --save \
    && npm install pm2 -g \
    && npm install -g sequelize-cli \
    && mkdir /ng-app \
    && chown -R node:node /ng-app \
    && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

# Migration
RUN sequelize db:migrate
RUN sequelize db:seed:all

USER node

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .
RUN mv docker.env .env

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "index.js"]
```

---

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  iproject-api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: api.dockerfile
    image: 'iproject-api'
    ports:
      - '3002:3002'
  iproject-web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    image: 'iproject-web:latest'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    links:
      - iproject-api
```

---

**This is the result, I got**

```
**docker-compose build --no-cache**

Building iproject-api
Step 1/11 : FROM node:9.3.0
 ---> 3d1823068e39
Step 2/11 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 68d259bbd036
Removing intermediate container 792b207a42ed
Step 3/11 : RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force
 ---> Running in ebd53a0f0e3d
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
 ---> cd598f62f4e5
Removing intermediate container ebd53a0f0e3d
Step 4/11 : RUN npm i && npm install nodemon --save     && npm install pm2 -g     && npm install -g sequelize-cli     && mkdir /ng-app     && chown -R node:node /ng-app     && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app
 ---> Running in 492ea3c40c22

> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v59-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@9.3.0 (node-v59 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory '/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function 'Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)':
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: 'v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.node-gyp/9.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3114): Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                                         ^
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY /node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
added 259 packages in 9.9s

> nodemon@1.14.10 postinstall /node_modules/nodemon
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[32mLove nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[96m\u001b[1mhttps://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate\u001b[0m\n')" || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ nodemon@1.14.10
added 246 packages in 7.093s
/usr/local/bin/pm2 -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
/usr/local/bin/pm2-dev -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
/usr/local/bin/pm2-runtime -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
/usr/local/bin/pm2-docker -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ pm2@2.9.1
added 251 packages in 6.35s
/usr/local/bin/sequelize -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize
+ sequelize-cli@3.2.0
added 105 packages in 3.718s
 ---> 19c196ba636a
Removing intermediate container 492ea3c40c22
Step 5/11 : RUN sequelize db:migrate
 ---> Running in cc84d0fbfc57

Sequelize CLI [Node: 9.3.0, CLI: 3.2.0, ORM: 4.31.0]

WARNING: This version of Sequelize CLI is not fully compatible with Sequelize v4. https://github.com/sequelize/cli#sequelize-support
```

> ERROR: Cannot find "/config/config.json". Have you run "sequelize init"?

How would one go about debugging this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sequelize` commands are likely looking for `config/config.json` in the current working directory. At the time of you running the command that is `/`. You probably want it to run with `/ng-app` as the working directory. For this, you could just move `WORKDIR /ng-app` above the `sequalize` commands.

Answer (score 21):

You can create a **.sequelizerc** config file for **Sequlize** CLI command for your project which tells **Sequlize** where to look for config files.

```
    var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  'config':          path.resolve('server', 'config', 'database.json'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('server', 'migrations'),
  'models-path':     path.resolve('server', 'models'),
  'seeders-path':    path.resolve('server', 'seeders'),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just run `sequelize init` and it will create config folder in your project and config.json in this folder.
after that change config.json as you want for connection

> "development": {
> "username": "postgres",
> "password": "123",
> "database": "user",
> "host": "localhost",
> "dialect": "postgres",
> "operatorsAliases": false   }

Answer (score 0):

For those using docker-compose: remember to include `config` and `models` folders into your volume list in `docker-compose.yml`. Took me a while to understand how to properly make everything work